# Slice string column based on length of another in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I need to slice a string column with variable offset based on the length of another string column. I have tried the below but I got the error (*TypeError: argument 'start': 'Expr' object cannot be interpreted as an integer*)

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("col1").str.slice(offset=pl.col('col2').str.len_chars())
               )
```

I am using Python **3.11.4** and Polars **0.19.17**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing pull request on Github regarding `str.slice`

- https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/13747

One potential workaround is to turn the string into a List and use the list functions.

- [`list.slice`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.slice.html#polars.Expr.list.slice)
- [`list.join`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.join.html#polars.Expr.list.join)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "col1": ["abcdefghijk", "abcde"], 
   "col2": ["abcde", "xy"]
})   

df.with_columns(slice = 
   pl.col("col1").str.extract_all(".")
     .list.slice(pl.col("col2").str.len_chars())
     .list.join("")
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ col1        ┆ col2  ┆ slice  │
│ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str         ┆ str   ┆ str    │
╞═════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ abcdefghijk ┆ abcde ┆ fghijk │
│ abcde       ┆ xy    ┆ cde    │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expr.str.slice` doesn't support expressions in its arguments: https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.slice.html

This could be a good feature request if you want to open one on the Polars github

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Any current workaround?

Comment: you could write a polars plugin